# Status Compilation error

Tags: javascript, олимпиада

> One day Alex was creating a contest about his friends, but
> accidentally deleted it. Fortunately, all the problems were saved, but
> now he needs to find them among other problems. But there are too many
> problems, to do it manually. Alex asks you to write a program, which
> will determine if a problem is from this contest by its name. It is
> known, that problem is from this contest if and only if its name
> contains one of Alex's friends' name exactly once. His friends' names
> are "Danil", "Olya", "Slava", "Ann" and "Nikita". Names are case
> sensitive. The only line contains string from lowercase and uppercase
> letters and "_" symbols of length, not more than 100 — the name of the
> problem. Print "YES", if problem is from this contest, and "NO"
> otherwise.

Oднажды Алекс создавал конкурс о своих друзьях, но случайно удалил его. К счастью, все проблемы были спасены, но теперь ему нужно найти их среди других проблем.

Но слишком много проблем, чтобы делать это вручную. Алекс просит вас написать программу, которая по названию определит, является ли проблема из этого конкурса.

Известно, что проблема в этом конкурсе тогда и только тогда, когда в его названии ровно один раз встречается имя одного из друзей Алекса . Его друзей зовут « Данил », « Оля », « Слава », « Анна » и « Никита ».

Имена чувствительны к регистру.

В единственной строке находится строка из строчных и прописных букв и символов « _ » длиной не более 100 - название задачи.

Выведите « YES », если задача из этого конкурса, и « NO » в противном случае.

```
let txt = 'NikitaAndString'

if (txt.indexOf('_') > -1) {
  console.log("No");
} else {
  console.log('Yes')
}
```

Это задание было на Олимпиаде, я скорее всего не понял его(Выходило "Compilation error". Можно ли его решить по-другому или правильно.

Comment: `problems` - не проблемы, а задачи (на конкурс). JS - не компилируемый язык, на секундочку. Compilation error - это сообщение тестирующей системы, которая не делает таких различий? Реальная ошибка во время выполнения кода как выглядит?

Comment: @mrEvgenX Сказали, если выходит такая ошибка, ответ неверный или у вас синтаксис неправильный

Comment: А в чем смысл вашего решения?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Если в строке имеется символ "_", то выдается No

Comment: @НурланМаннапов это понятно, непонятно как это решает вашу задачу?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Просто задача была неясна, можете объяснить как решить её, то есть шаги, а код я сам напишу

Comment: Вам непонятна задача или непонятно, как решать ее? Это две разные вещи)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko И то и другое)))

Comment: С первым помочь не могу. А из-за этого не могу помочь и со вторым :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko :) Спасибо за плодотворную беседу